# Facing This Problem while debug my flutter program. Doctor it Okay

Tags: flutter, debugging, web-applications

I've tried upgrding, re installing and with different IDE
When debug and running this error occured.

My Flutter doctor is okay, I've enabled flutter web also.

Failed to compile application.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:14:1: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both     
'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
import 'asset_manifest.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' 
is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:32:31: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both
'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
AssetManifest assetManifest = AssetManifest();
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.0.5/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:71:13: Error: Method not found:
'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_web-5.1.2/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:264:9: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
  throw FallThroughError();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.8.5/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:17:
13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.11.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart:65:15: Error: The method
'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'.
 - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart'
 ('/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.11.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
        throw FallThroughError();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:28:13: Error:
'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.   
      .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:125:10: Error: A value of type      
'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
         ^
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             44.8s
Failed to compile application.
```

Comment: Hi, if possible, could you please share some of your code related to this? :)